# getConnection() with out assign variable will leak a connection

Tags: java, connection-pooling

I am using the jdbc connection pooling and if I write code like

```
DatabaseMetaData dbMeta = getConnection().getMetaData();
```

where getConnection() results connection object. Is this results connection leak?
Here the returned connection is not explicitly closing.

Comment: Very likely yes. Why would it be somehow different here than all the other cases where you need to make sure the connection is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per JavaDocs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html

> **Connection**
>
>   A connection (session) with a specific database. SQL statements are
>   executed and results are returned within the context of a connection.

whereas `getMetaData()` is for
Retrieving DatabaseMetaData object that contains metadata about the database to which this Connection object represents a connection. The metadata includes information about the database's tables, its supported SQL grammar, its stored procedures, the capabilities of this connection, and so on.
Returns:
a DatabaseMetaData object for this Connection object

So `getMetaData()` can be used to validate the connection object validity also `getConnection()` is responsible for creating connection object and `getMetaData()` can be used to get the information related to above stated points. Also as stated all the points above you have to make sure your connections are closed to avoid any memory leakage after use of each connection.

Comment: Thanks Rishal.

So this will be the correct way of writing the code.

Connection con = getConnection();
DatabaseMetaData dbMeta = con.getMetaData(); 


at end of the code

con.close();

Comment: Thanks a lot Rishal.